# How to send special characters using utl_http?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to send some text using utl_http. The Text I'm sending includes special characters

```
    Declare
      HttpRequest      utl_http.req;
      HttpResponse     utl_http.resp;      
      ResponseText     clob;
      URL              varchar2(500) := 'someurl';
      PostPrameters    varchar2(30000);              

    begin
      PostPrameters := 'From=SenderName&To=+336...&Body=très cool';    
      PostPrameters := utl_url.escape(PostPrameters);
      URL := utl_url.escape(URL); 

      HttpRequest := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST', 'HTTP/1.1');    
      utl_http.set_authentication(HttpRequest, TwilioUserName, TwilioPassword);
      
      utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest,'Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
      utl_http.set_header(HttpRequest, 'Content-Length',length(PostPrameters));
      utl_http.write_text(HttpRequest, PostPrameters);    
      HttpResponse := utl_http.get_response(HttpRequest);    
      utl_http.read_text(HttpResponse,ResponseText);   
      utl_http.end_response(HttpResponse);    
    end;
```

The body of the text I'm sending should be "très cool"

When sending the request, it's received as "trï¿½s cool"

I tried to add **UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');** but it's not working.

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use `URL := utl_url.escape(URL,false,'UTF-8');`

Comment: this actually skips the special characters. I don't want to be skipped. I want to be sent normally

Comment: What about  `URL := utl_url.escape(URL, TRUE,'UTF-8');` ?

Comment: Or there is always `'tr&egrave;s cool'` if this is fixed text.